# Phantomjs does not render iFrame

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, export-to-pdf

I have very annoying issue when I'm trying to export iFrame content on my page to PDF with PhantomJS by `page.render` function it shows everything in PDF except iFrame content,  `--web-security=no` flag also didn't work.
Is it really impossible or I missed something?

Comment: Have you tried `--disable-web-security` ?

Comment: No, I didn't know about that one, also it does not exist in the documention

Comment: It's not working, iFrames dont get rendered anyhow, it's a bug what everybody are talking about. Phantom.js has problems with rendering iFrames, I would expect to see exported pdf as I would see it on a real browser

Comment: @TaronMehrabyan have you solved the issue somehow, i've faced with the same problem the content of iframe is not being rendered properly, that messes up pdf structure exported?

Answer (score -1):

try casperjs
or try evaluate to get the contents and render them separately